# REG-exp negating at end of line

Tags: sed

I have ending lines like

```
"true"/>
testname="A01
"true">
Prop>
testname="A02
```

Wanted to insert some text at the end of lines containing testname="A0...

I tried below option

```
sed -i 's/!>$/_\" enabled=\"true\">/g' file
sed -i 's/!>\\n/_\" enabled=\"true\">/g' file
```

However it is not reflecting in the file.
    any tweak is needed for this. Help me out on this

Comment: The input seems to be XML. Use a proper XML parser to modify it.

Comment: Post some input and output examples.

Comment: Hi Miindlek, in output i am not seeing any changes in the file.Iput file is XML file

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`

```
awk '/="A0[0-9]+$/ {$0=$0" blabla"}1' file
"true"/>
testname="A01 blabla
"true">
Prop>
testname="A02 blabla
```

To update original file:

```
awk '/="A0[0-9]+$/ {$0=$0" blabla"}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull with sourroung space (code below don't use any space in pattern)

```
sed -i -e '/^testname="A[0-9]\{1,\}$/ a\
put some line\
to add\
here' YourFile
```

option `g` is not needed because you add a line and sed works (by default) line by line

Answer (score 0):

Try the below GNU `sed` command,

```
sed -ri '/A0[0-9]+$/ s/(^.*testname=")(.*)$/\1\2_" enabled="true">/g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ sed -r '/A0[0-9]+$/ s/(^.*testname=")(.*)$/\1\2_" enabled="true">/g' c
"true"/>
testname="A01_" enabled="true">
"true">
Prop>
testname="A02_" enabled="true">
```